# display user data using logined session

Tags: php, session

please i'm having difficulty display user data from my database using session after a successful login
below is my program code in the page i want the data to appear
NOTE: this page already contain a session and logout function

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "INDEX.PHP";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Ark_softwares";
$password = "";
$dbname = "digitals";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM admin_login WHERE username = '$session'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct `username = '$session'`?

Comment: Do two things :
1)print_r() your session variable
2)check your $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM admin_login WHERE username = '$session'"; query.

Comment: your variable `$session` came from nowhere

Answer (score -1):

I can't find the place where you are defigning the value '$session', it looks like you aren't even checking or the session isn't null. What I should do in your place is using the `session_destroy()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) function of PHP to logout.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    session_destroy();
}
```

You are able to logout with only putting "?logout" after your URL.

Beside that if I were you, I should only store the user id in the session so you have an unique field you can get the user information from.

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['user_id']);
$sql = 'SELECT firstname, lastname, username FROM admin_login WHERE id=\'' . $id . '\'';
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['firstname'];
```